# Creating a client_id and registering an account using OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, api-design

When authorizing a user for a first party mobile app API, I send the following request:

`localhost:5000/oauth/token?client_id=9qFbZD4udTgFVYo0u5U9kZX2iuzbdcJDRAquTfRk&grant_type=password&username=MyUsername&password=MyPassword`

The issue with this is that I need to already have an account created as well as a client_id available.

My question is, when a user downloads my app, how should I send a request to my API to create a client record (which requires a user to create since I have a foreign key linking the client to the user's ID) and user record in my database since there is not an authorization token? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

well, you are using `password` grant type here, that means user understand and trust your oauth server and pass username/password to it. Other thing is that client_id is not meant to be unique for each user, its and id of application which user is going to use, so yes - its usualy aquired once during integrating client application and authorization server.

I believe you should take a look at `authorization_code` grant type.

Comment: The only issue with the authorization code grant type is that I have to redirect to a different page to confirm the request, which would be odd since this is my own API. Wouldn't it be better to implement a password grant? I understand that the client_id is unique for each mobile app instance too, however I don't know how to secure creating an account or signing in when I have no access_token since I need email and password credentials to do so

Comment: you can use password grant but you wont omit creating an account:) as you wrote just creating new one on each request could be dangerous. But you could redirect to your own 'authorize' page + register user there + confirm on email etc. Maybe you should put more details about your usecase, so it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

When any client installs your application, you can let client register first into the application. When the client registers it will hit one of the API that you have to create the client details into the system. After the client has registered then you can allow him to login and continue doing the token authentication.

User can either register into your application or use third party login like Facebook or Google for registering into the system provided your application trusts these identity providers.

Comment: So basically I should have my API exposed without OAuth to create a client record in my database and then from there, allow the user access to register?

Comment: The ouath is only for securing some information that you dont want unauthorized user to access. So as far as your important information is secured using oauth that API will be protected by the token. But as far as registration is concerned yes you can let user provide credentials for registration otherwise there is no way for you to know who is a valid user. We will not be adding users manually as it will restrict the number of users a system can get.

Comment: Right I see, would there not be a security issue too with someone reverse engineering my private API and filling my database with lots of spam users?

Comment: I dont think that can be solved with Oauth. The security you are looking for with oauth can only secure the private data behind some of the public API. Apart from that if you want to get rid of some other issues there are other ways. But oauth will solve one of your issue for sure. The only api that will be open is for registration and nothing else so there is no way someone can get into the api which protect secure data.

Answer (score 0):

From reading up on the answer and comments, if you are also implementing a custom backend for this, wouldn't it be better if you just send this?

```
localhost:5000/oauth/token?client_id=9qFbZD4udTgFVYo0u5U9kZX2iuzbdcJDRAquTfRk
```

From here, in your backend, just have a user table that stores this token and check to see if there is a matching token. If there isn't then create a new user object and have the user fill out the appropriate response (email, password, etc) to complete the registration.

To solve the spambot issue, either have a robot validator where certain failed attempt will kick the user out and delete the temp user obj or have the backend send a validation email to the email address it received to make sure that the email is valid.

If whatever the reason you want/need to use client_id+user+password in your url like in your question, you can do multi check where

1. client_id is new or it already exist
2. username exists

From there still send them to the registration page and fill out new user if it is taken or pre-fill the user and password that they designated

For added security I would suggest that you scramble user's password before you make that request or it could get sniped by a packet snooper